# setting the roles for the user when using Google/FB/Github as Authorization server

Tags: google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client, oauth2-server

I am planning to use Google as my OAuth2 Authorization server. How to configure the roles for the user, in case we are using Google,FB,Github as our Auth server? My Spring Security expects the roles/authorities to allow/deny access to the protected resource.